# How to use same object in windows forms/classes without creating new ones?

Tags: c#, .net, socket.io

I'm new to C# and OOP (I know, it's not an excuse). I'm trying to create a simple socket.io based chatting app. There's a main form and there's a chatting interface. I need the socket object on both of these forms. But the thing is I don't know how to define them. To say it better; when I create socket object in two of these, program creates a new object each time so ex socket session gets terminated. I need to create a socket object and use it in multiple forms/classes.

Edit:
My code in mainform that creates new object:

```
Socket socket = IO.Socket("http://localhost:3000");
```

I use that same code in the child form(chatting interface)

Comment: [How to implement the singleton pattern in C#](https://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Singleton)

Comment: If you posted your code which creates new cbjects over and over, someone might be able to tell you how to fix it.  Otherwise, the answer is to hold onto the original reference which may require a form level object variable.

Comment: In general, if you want to provide other classes access to something, you would create a `public` property or method on the class that returns the instance of the object. Or could also make the object `public static` if there's no requirement for the consumers to have an instance of the containing class first (i.e. to set some state).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you are new to software patterns. The singleton suggestion isn't bad but it may be too complex for what you need.

You can have a single use of your socket instance used in multiple environments by initializing it ONE time and using it MANY times. This leads us to question, when do you initialize it and how do you access it from different places within the program?

You know how to initialize it

```
Socket socket = IO.Socket("http://localhost:3000");
```

As for "when" - you should initialize before or on the first time it's used. So when the Form gets created is a good place, or even in Program.cs before you launch the form if you already have all your connection info.

To access it from either location, consider making a static helper class to hold your socket.

```
public static class SocketService {
    public static Socket socket { get; set; }
    public static void Init() {
        socket = IO.Socket("http://localhost:3000");
    }
}
```

Then when you want to use the from anywhere in the app, you can say

```
SocketService.socket.DoPost(somepayload);
```

Before you use the socket, be sure to call

```
SocketService.Init();
```

This will reset your connection.